# httpd24 install not possible, unpacking failed

Tags: centos7, yum, httpd

I have a problem with httpd server on centos 7. First package was not updatable, then I remove and try to reinstall httpd24-httpd but I always have following error: `error: unpacking of archive failed on file /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules: cpio: rename`
It seems something with the opt folder but I don't know where it could come from.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution, delete the httpd folder in opt and reinstall.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/468403)

Comment: @bjoster Why do you say this is not a complete answer?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I didn't. I voted for including this answer as an edit in the post and SF put the comment. Additionally, as the answer does not really "answer" it (like what path to delete [httpd24 often has multiple ones] and what mechanism used to update it, which failed), I thought it may helpful to include this in the question itself so that somebody may answer it more completely (by pointing out a real bug or really working workaround).

Comment: @bjoster I do not completely understand, what I have to add?